# Is a non-block socket always writable after it finishes its connection in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I want to build a port map tool in python from scratch. Basically it is a TCP proxy that transits all the traffic between the client and the objective service or application.

Specifically, For every connection I create two sockets who are responsible to communicate to the client and objective service respectively. To implement IO-multiplexing feature, I use module `selectors` to monitor the `EVENT_READ` and `EVENT_WRITE` event on these two sockets. However I find that the sockets are always writable so that the main loop doesn't block at all. Is it normal? My code is as follows:

```py
import socket
import selectors

def recv_from(sock):
    data = b''
    try:
        while True:
            chunk = sock.recv(4096)
            if not chunk:
                break
            data += chunk
    except:
        pass
    return data

class RelayHandlder:

    def __init__(self, client_sock, remote_sock, selector):
        '''
        client_sock and remote_sock have already finished the connection.
        '''
        self._client_sock = client_sock
        self._remote_sock = remote_sock
        self._selector = selector

        self._send_buffer = b''
        self._recv_buffer = b''

        self._selector.register(self._client_sock, selectors.EVENT_READ|selectors.EVENT_WRITE, self._client_handler)
        self._selector.register(self._remote_sock, selectors.EVENT_READ|selectors.EVENT_WRITE, self._remote_handler)

    def _client_handler(self, client_sock, mask):
        if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
            data = recv_from(client_sock)
            if data:                
                self._send_buffer = data
            else:
                self._close()
        elif mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
            if self._recv_buffer:
                try:
                    client_sock.send(self._recv_buffer)
                    self._recv_buffer = b''
                except OSError:
                    self._close()

    def _remote_handler(self, remote_sock, mask):
        if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
            data = recv_from(remote_sock)
            if data:
                self._recv_buffer = data
            else:
                self._close()
        elif mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
            if self._send_buffer:
                try:
                    remote_sock.send(self._send_buffer)
                    self._send_buffer = b''
                except OSError:
                    self._close()

    def _close(self):
        print('Closing ...')
        self._selector.unregister(self._client_sock)
        self._client_sock.close()
        self._selector.unregister(self._remote_sock)
        self._remote_sock.close()
        self._send_buffer = b''
        self._recv_buffer = b''

class PortMapper:
    '''
    Map the remote port to local.
    '''

    def __init__(self, proxy_ip, proxy_port, remote_ip, remote_port):
        self.proxy_ip = proxy_ip
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        self.remote_ip = remote_ip
        self.remote_port = remote_port

        self._selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

        self._proxy_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        while True:
            try:
                self._proxy_sock.bind((proxy_ip, proxy_port))
                break
            except OSError:
                proxy_port += 1
                self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        self._proxy_sock.listen(10)
        self._proxy_sock.setblocking(False)
        self._selector.register(self._proxy_sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, self._accept_handler)
        print('Listening at {}:{}'.format(proxy_ip, proxy_port))

    def _accept_handler(self, proxy_sock, mask):
        client_sock, addr = proxy_sock.accept()
        client_sock.setblocking(False)
        print('Accept from {}'.format(addr))

        remote_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_sock.setblocking(False)
        try:
            remote_sock.connect((self.remote_ip, self.remote_port))
        except BlockingIOError:
            pass

        RelayHandlder(client_sock, remote_sock, self._selector)

    def loop(self):
        while True:
            events = self._selector.select()
            for key, mask in events:
                callback = key.data
                callback(key.fileobj, mask)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Port Map Tool.')
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--remote-host', required=True, type=str, help='Remote host.')
    parser.add_argument('-P', '--remote-port', required=True, type=int, help='Remote port.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--local-port', default=1000, type=int, help='Local port.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    PortMapper('0.0.0.0', args.local_port, args.remote_host, args.remote_port).loop()
```

In the code, `self._send_buffer` in `RelayHandler` is used to cache the data received from the client. If `self._remote_sock` is writable and `self._send_buffer` is not empty, the proxy will send `self._send_buffer` to the remote service. The logic is similar for `self._client_sock`. The main loop is defined on `loop` function in `PortMapper`.

I have two questions:

- Is a non-block socket always writable after it finishes its connection in python?
- In the above code, sockets are always writable while buffers are often empty. So for every single loop in the main loop, `self._selector.select()` will always return without blocking, and the callback is executed to do nothing but only to see if the buffer is empty, which may hurt the performance. Is there a better method or structure to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A socket is normally writable until the system buffer is full. That is the reason why many simple `select` multiplexed system only considere the read part and assume that they will be able to write or accept the possibility of being blocked if they are not.

If you want to be super safe and ensure that you will be able to write, you should ignore EVENT_WRITE unless you are ready to write something. But to prevent your code to exhaust the local memory buffer, the relay should stop reading (also ignore EVENT_READ) if the other channel cannot write.